# why the javascript toggle code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have added the **Prototype** library to my site, then add the following code. but when i click the span, the ul content is not hidden. the link href still work.

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    Event.observe('.block-category li.parent span', 'click', function(e){
        $('.block-category li.parent ul').toggle();
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});
```

html:

```
    <div class="block block-category">
    <li class="level-top  parent">
    <a href="example.com/...."><span>text one</span></a>
    <ul> //the 1 ul
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="level-top"><a href="..."><span>....</span></a></li>


  <li class="level-top  parent">
    <a href="example.com/...."><span>text two</span></a>
    <ul> //the 2 ul
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>
  <li class="level-top  parent">
    <a href="example.com/...."><span>text three</span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>....</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </div>
```

thank you.

**ps**: when click **text one**, the the 1 ul toggle. when click  **text two**the 2 ul toggle, ...

Comment: Simple typo -- class selectors must start with "`.`", i.e. `block-category li.parent` needs to be `.block-category li.parent`.

Comment: I don't know Protoype. But, I observe that click listener itself is not fired in this code

Comment: when i add the  ".", the show/hide still not work.thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are using CSS selectors as arguments to Prototype's `$()` and `Event.observe()` functions. Neither of these functions accepts a selector. They both expect element IDs instead.

You can use `$$()` instead of `$()` and give it a selector. Note that this returns an array of extended elements and not just a single one.

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/observe/
http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/
http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/

Comment: i add $$ to my code,but  still not works well. how to correct it.thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should try `$$` to select multiple elements and then call observe for each one of them:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    $$('.block-category li.parent > a span').each(function (element) {
        element.observe('click', function (e) {
            e.element().up().next('ul').toggle();
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, it's only the first ul in the first li works ok. but the last doesn't work. how to make others ul in the li also work

Comment: when i click another text in span('.block-category li.parent span' ). it can't show/hide. it contros the fist (.block-category li.parent ul) show and hide.

Comment: i am sorry, when i click(.block-category li.parent span) all the content are hidden. thank yuo

Comment: all the content are disappeared, how to correct the code. thank you

Comment: what do you want to hide exactly?

Comment: when click the text in the span, the ul under it is hidden. the ul only in li (the click span parent) is hidden.

Comment: it's ok . many thanks. now, i want to all the default state of  ul is hidden, i add $$('.block-category li.parent ul').hide(); under Event.observe(window, 'load', function() { line. why it doesn't work. thank you

Comment: oh,no. when i first open the page, when i click. it will redirect to the link. when the second time. it's ok. i put the js code under the html code.

Comment: If you put the code under HTML tags then no need to call `Event.observe(window, 'load', ...)`.